# kafka-streams session windows retention period

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I am doing POC on session windows for one of the stream requirements i have. For this i am using Session windows as this fits requirement where i have to aggregate the events with unique transaction id into list. Each transaction can have multiple events generated by different applications and push them to kafka.  Below is the code

```
    StreamsConfig streamsConfig = new StreamsConfig(getProperties());
    Serde<String> stringSerde = Serdes.String();
    Serde<Transaction> transactionSerde = StreamsSerdes.TransactionSerde();

    Aggregator<String,Transaction, List<Transaction>> agg = (key, value, list)
            -> {
        list.add(value);
        return list;
    };

    Merger<String, List<Transaction>> merger = (key, v1, v2) ->
       Stream.concat(v1.stream(), v2.stream())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Materialized<String,List<Transaction>,SessionStore<Bytes, byte[]>>
            materialized = Materialized.<String,List<Transaction>>as(Stores
            .persistentSessionStore
            ("trans-store", 1000 * 30)).withKeySerde(stringSerde).withValueSerde(StreamsSerdes
            .TransactionsListSerde());


    Initializer<List<Transaction>> init = () -> new ArrayList<>();

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    KTable<Windowed<String>, List<Transaction>> customerTransactionCounts =
             builder.stream(TRANSACTIONS_TOPIC, Consumed.with(stringSerde, transactionSerde).withOffsetResetPolicy(LATEST))
            .groupBy((noKey, transaction) -> transaction.getCustomerId(),
                    Serialized.with(stringSerde, transactionSerde))
            .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(10000).until(1000 * 30))
                     .aggregate(init,agg,merger,materialized);


    customerTransactionCounts.toStream().print(Printed.<Windowed<String>, List<Transaction>>toSysOut()
            .withLabel("Customer Transactions List").withKeyValueMapper((key, list) ->
                    ("Current Time " + new Date().toString() + " Customer Id - " + key.key()  +
                    " START " +
                    new Date
                    (key.window().start()).toString() + " --- END " + new Date(key.window().end()).toString()+ "  " + list)));


    KafkaStreams kafkaStreams = new KafkaStreams(builder.build(), streamsConfig);
    kafkaStreams.cleanUp();
```

How does the retention period work here??

1) First i ingested some data with transaction id X with events date range from

**START Mon Apr 16 22:25:40 EDT 2018 --- END Mon Apr 16 22:25:49 EDT 2018**

All of them were aggregated as they fall into same session.

2) Next i ingested single record transaction id X time **START Mon Apr 16 22:26:45 EDT 2018.**

I see 1 record after commit interval as expected

Here as per my understanding the stream time changed to **22:26:45**. At this point the records ingested above should be expired from state store as endtime < stream time - retention period (30 secs)

3) Next i ingested record single record transaction id X that falls into the same time range as the first set of events. I see all the records from the first step and the new current record in the aggregated results after commit interval.

Shouldn't the first set of record be expired from state store as they are past the retention period???

In the third step i was assuming i would get only one aggregated record as the older ones should have been removed. When would the retention period kick in to remove records from state store??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retention time is a "minimum" -- for more efficient expiration, data is stored in so-called segments (based on time intervals), and segments are expired when all data in a segment passed retention time.

Comment: Thanks @Matthias. Can you post the link if there is any  documentation around how the segmenting and its retention logic works?  As per my know segment is per time interval. I am trying to replicate the retention clean up behaviour but couldn't get it. 

Lets say if the segment length is 60 secs and the number of segments is 3 then if state store gets any data that doesn't belong to any of the 3 existing segments then it should clean up on of the old segments and purge the data.. is that right understanding??

Comment: There is no docs... only code :( -- your understanding is correct: if you have 3 segments, older data would just be dropped and if newer data arrived, that goes into a new segment, the oldest segment is purged.